# Azure Mobile App Offline Sync doesn't return on first execute

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

Appreciate any help regarding issue in my XF + Azure Mobile App + Offline Sync. I have a mobile application developed using Xamarin form with the following flow:

Common Startup Flow A:

1. Create azure service objects (MobileServiceClient)
2. Create db store objects (MobileServiceSQLiteStore)
3. Register entity to sqlite table via DefineTable()
4. MobileServiceClient.SyncContext.InitializeAsync()
5. Check for cached auth token

Branch Flow B : Invalid/No Token found (First launch)

6. Display login page (XF)
7. Perform custom authentication via MobileServiceClient.InvokeApiAsync()
8. Extract GWT auth token from response (failed scenario is omitted here)
9. Cache auth token for future usage (with token expiry info)

Branch Flow C : Valid Token found (Subsequent launch)

10. Create azure service user from token (MobileServiceUser)
11. Associate user to azure service object
    MobileServiceClient.CurrentUser = 
    MobileServiceClient.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken =
12. Perform synchronisation
    MobileServiceClient.SyncContext.PushAsync()
    MobileServiceClient.GetSyncTable().PullAsync()

My problem is, when i do flow A->B->C, my synchronisation is not returning from PushAsync().
Once I force closed my app and re-launch into flow A->C, everything will work properly (PushAsync() completes and PullSync() retrieve data from remote).

I also tried to remove the "redundant" PushAsync() in step #12, but still face the same issue where synchronisation became not returning from PullAsync().

I'm suspecting this has something to do with threading (though I'm using async/await extensively and these should has nothing to do with threading) because once in a while the same procedure (first launch + first sync) will able to work (returned properly).

Some materials for reference:

[Synchronizing Offline Data with Azure Mobile Apps](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/sync/azure-mobile-apps/)

[Enable offline sync for your Xamarin.Forms mobile app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-offline-data)

[Offline Data Sync in Azure Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync)

Comment: appreciate if down-voting comes with reason behind, else its really "helpful" and "constructive"

Comment: More details are needed.  Code snippets showing your flow, what do the backend logs look like?  Are you getting an exception but it's being swallowed somehow?  Wrap the pullasync() method explicitly.  Finally, download the symbolsource and/or github project and step through the code with a debugger.  Otherwise, this is unknowable.

Comment: @AdrianHall, the codebase are too huge to post here, maybe i'll clean it up and set the git repo to public, as my question stated, there isn't any exception but the method never returns (verified by placing diagnostic logs before and after the call)

Comment: You are guaranteed to be bumping into a threading issue.  I've not heard of a problem with something freezing - it sometimes pauses for a long time during a particular harsh "first sync" scenario - but the async/await takes care of it.  Boil it down to a simpler use case that still demonstrates the issue rather than posting all your code.

Comment: @AdrianHall yea tried wrapping it in Task.Run() but still the same behavior